# using Group by and order by in the one query and it is giving me the formula parse error

Tags: sql, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=iferror(QUERY({BBSM},"SELECT Col"&MATCH("Contract",'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",SUM(Col"&MATCH("Unit Cost", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&") WHERE Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0) &"='SSB' GROUP BY Col"&MATCH("Contract",'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&") order by Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0) DESC),{"BLANK,BLANK,BLANK"})
```

Comment: Please apply suitable formatting options to your question. It is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing `&` before the DESC term:

```
"=iferror(QUERY({BBSM},"SELECT Col"&MATCH("Contract",'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",SUM(Col"&MATCH("Unit Cost", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&") WHERE Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0) &"='SSB' GROUP BY Col"&MATCH("Contract",'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Stock Type", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&",Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&") order by Col"&MATCH("Purchase Date", 'BB - SM'!1:1,0)&"DESC"),{"BLANK,BLANK,BLANK"})"
```

On a new sheet it will now return the default value defined in `IFERROR`:

[image]